# Filter results with ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I am new to ionic, following some tutorials and trying to learn and apply other stuff. I think what I'm trying to achieve is quite simple, but I can't seem to have it working.

What I'm trying to do is simply to filter results using the ion-select element to display its correspondent pick from the select.

So what I have is this ion-select where I'm using the ngModel and ngFor to filter which options the user should have, and once the user select their option, the app should only display the correspondent results, in this case, a Sport (so if the user picks 'Soccer' in the ion-select, only the 'Soccer' ion-cards should be displayed, I have those connected in the back end.

I'm adding here a piece of the code, but I'm afraid you might need other piece of code to get it more clear, so let me know please. Cheers guys!

```
<ion-content padding>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Filter by Sport</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="list" multiple="true">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.sport}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of list">    
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>{{item.title}}</ion-card-title>
        <p>Sport: {{item.sport}}</p>
        <p>Participants: {{item.players}}</p>
        <p>When: {{item.when}}</p>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <p>Location: {{item.location}}</p>
        <button ion-button block (click)="joinEvent(item)">Join!</button>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Edit: Added .ts code below:

```
export class JoinEventPage {

  filterListBy$
  filteredList$

    list: IEvent[];
  joined = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams, 
              public eventProvider: EventsProvider,
          public joinedEventsProvider: JoinedEventsProvider) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){

    // create observable
    this.filterListBy$ = Observable.from(this.list)
      // pull out just the name of the sport
      .map((a: any) => a.sport)
      // make sure items are distinct
      .distinct()
      // return an array
      .toArray();

    // force the initial filtering of the list
    this.changeCategory([])

    // this.eventProvider.listEvents().subscribe(res=>{
    //  this.list = res;
    // }, error => {
    //  console.log("Error: " + error.message);
    // });

    // this.joinedEventsProvider.getStorage('joined-events').then(res => {
    //   if(res){
    //     this.joined = res;
    //   }
    // });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad JoinEventPage');
  }

  joinEvent(item){
    for(let event of this.joined){
      if(event.id == item.id){
        console.log("You already joined this event!")
        return;
      }
    }
    this.joined.push(item);
    this.joinedEventsProvider.setStorage('joined-events', this.joined);
  }

  changeCategory(_value) {
    // if nothing selected, show all
    if (!_value.length) {
      return this.filteredList$ = Observable.from(this.list).toArray();
    }

    // if something selected, filter the list based on the item selected which 
    // will be in the array parameter "_value"
    this.filteredList$ = Observable.from(this.list)
      .filter((i) => { return _value.indexOf(i.sport) !== -1 })
      .toArray()
  }

}
```

Solution: The only change I did to the .ts file following Aaron's solution is below:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.eventProvider.listEvents().subscribe(res=>{
    this.list = res; 

     // create observable
    this.filterListBy$ = Observable.from(this.list)
      // pull out just the name of the sport
      .map((a: any) => a.sport)
      // make sure items are distinct
      .distinct()
      // return an array
      .toArray();

    // force the initial filtering of the list
    this.changeCategory([])

    this.joinedEventsProvider.getStorage('joined-events').then(res => {
        if(res){
          this.joined = res;
        }
      });

    });


  }
```

Comment: Change `[(ngModel)]="list" with [(ngModel)]="selectedList"` and create global variable for name `selectedList`. And your `ion-option` tag hasn't `[value]` attribute. Plese add this attribute your `ion-option` tag. For ex: `[value]='item.sport'`.

Comment: @Omsl thanks, I'm trying to work out your idea, but no luck. Could you add your example to the code? I was thinking that the 'list' still needed to be there because it holds all the items that could be filtered, but I get your idea of having the selectedList to hold the ones that the user picked, I'm just not able to put them to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see full answer here, but highlights are below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-tkqzr6

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // create observable
    this.filterListBy$ = Observable.from(this.list)
      // pull out just the name of the sport
      .map((a: any) => a.sport)
      // make sure items are distinct
      .distinct()
      // return an array
      .toArray();

    // force the initial filtering of the list
    this.onChange([])
  }
```

when the user selects an option, we call onChange

```
  onChange(_value) {
    // if nothing selected, show all
    if (!_value.length) {
      return this.filteredList$ = Observable.from(this.list).toArray();
    }

    // if something selected, filter the list based on the item selected which 
    // will be in the array parameter "_value"
    this.filteredList$ = Observable.from(this.list)
      .filter((i) => { return _value.indexOf(i.sport) !== -1 })
      .toArray()
  }
```

now in the html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Filter by Sport</ion-label>
    <ion-select multiple="true" (ionChange)="onChange($event)">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of (filterListBy$ | async)">{{item}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Aaron, this is exactly the behaviour I'm looking for, thanks very much. Now, I'm trying to addapt your idea to my app, but I'm getting an error that says 'underfined it not observable'. Googling it wasn't very clear because I saw many different situations for this error. It might have something to do with the list being pulled from the backend I set up? I added the .ts code to my post there so you can have a look on how I was initially populating the screen, by pulling the information from my provider (the code is commentated because I'm trying to use your idea). Thanks again Aaron

Comment: Aaron, I take that back I was able to make it work and will add the solution to my post. Again, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: if the solution worked, you should mark it as correct... glad I was able to help

Comment: Hi Aaron, the thing that I'm noticing though is that it is not persisting really well, whether I change tabs for instance, it goes back to displaying the entire list, even if the ion-select is still checked. Would you have a suggestion on that? I edited the post with how I was able to fit in your suggestion so far. Thanks again!

Comment: move the code from `ngOnInit` to another lifecycle method that is called whenever  the page in rendered